# Unable to provision rabbitmq using chef and testkitchen

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra

I am trying to install an old version of RabbitMQ using Chef (cookbook 'rabbitmq', '~> 5.8.5') and Kitchen, below my configuration:

**Attributes**

```ruby
#Erlang
default['erlang']['install_method'] = 'source'
default['erlang']['source']['version']='R13B03'
default['erlang']['source']['checksum']='e7c46c8b2778f22064a3b369c1a1b572a1cc0e8a2198166858d4b9a1b488d662'

#RabbitMQ
default['rabbitmq']['erlang']['enabled'] = true
default['rabbitmq']['version'] = "3.4.4"
default['rabbitmq']['rpm_package'] ='rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm'
```

**Recipe:**

```ruby
include_recipe 'rabbitmq::default'
```

When I run kitchen converge, I am getting the following exception:

```
Running handlers:
   [2020-08-22T22:20:07+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
   Running handlers complete
   [2020-08-22T22:20:07+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
   Chef Infra Client failed. 9 resources updated in 06 minutes 26 seconds
   [2020-08-22T22:20:07+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
   [2020-08-22T22:20:07+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
   [2020-08-22T22:20:07+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: rpm_package[/tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm] (rabbitmq::default line 224) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
   ---- Begin output of ["rpm", "-i", "/tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm"] ----
   STDOUT:
   STDERR: warning: /tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 056e8e56: NOKEY
   error: Failed dependencies:
   erlang >= R13B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch
   ---- End output of ["rpm", "-i", "/tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm"] ----
   Ran ["rpm", "-i", "/tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm"] returned 1
```

But when I logged in to the VM, I can see erlang is installed:

```
[vagrant@kitchen-rmq-server-centos-7 ~]$ erl
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
    
Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

And it is the same version required by RMQ (R13B03)
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Edit: to replicate the issue https://github.com/Proximator/chef-rmq

Comment: do you have a repository to share and reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Mr. I created a repo to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/Proximator/chef-rmq

Comment: you are missing `Gemfile.lock`, this makes bundler gem resolution run too long so i had to kill it. please add the lock file and then i will try to take a deeper look

Comment: @Mr. I added it, thanks for your help

Comment: Can you log into your VM and try running manually the same command Chef tries: `rpm -i /tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm` (as a root). What would be the output?

Comment: @DracoAter 
warning: /tmp/kitchen/cache/rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 056e8e56: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        erlang >= R13B-03 is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.4.4-1.noarch

Comment: So it's not Chef problem. You need to solve the dependency problem of the rabbitmq. Probably rpm does not have erlang package, and your erlang is installed somehow else.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we have to make sure erlang is installed by the `rabbitmq` cookbook, and not by any other means. This is the note found on Chef supermarket for [rabbitmq cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/rabbitmq):

> The packages are **cannot be installed alongside with other Erlang packages**, for example, those from standard Debian repositories or Erlang Solutions.
>
> To make sure that the Erlang cookbook is not used by `rabbitmq::default`

Also, there is a [compatibility matrix](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html) of RabbitMQ and Erlang versions. RabbitMQ 3.7.0 being the lowest supported version, for which the lowest compatible Erlang version is 19.3.

There are zero dependency Erlang RPMs "*just enough to run RabbitMQ*" as documented here:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm

**For example - to install RabbitMQ 3.7.x with the compatible Erlang 19.3.x:**

You should have these attributes:

```ruby
default['rabbitmq']['erlang']['enabled'] = true
default['rabbitmq']['version'] = '3.7.6'
default['rabbitmq']['erlang']['yum']['baseurl'] = 'https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/rpm/erlang/19/el/7'
default['rabbitmq']['erlang']['version'] = '19.3.6.13'
```

Then include below recipes:

```ruby
include_recipe 'rabbitmq::erlang_package'
include_recipe 'rabbitmq::default'
```

Comment: I tried that but then it is installing the latest erlang (22) not the version R13B03

Comment: Latest is installed by default, but it can be changed/set by: `node['rabbitmq']['erlang']['version']`

Comment: Btw, RabbitMQ 3.4.4 seems to be an [unsupported release](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html). And so the compatible rabbitmq-erlang may not be available. Why do you want to use this version?